Why is Microsoft Access module throwing "Run-time error 3061, too few parameters"?
ORIGINAL POST:
I created several modules within Microsoft Access that run within the Access window "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications".  Each module consists of a series of about 30-80 SQL queries stored within my Access database, to operate on tables stored within my Access database stored on my hard drive.
All the modules ran just fine last week, but two of them started throwing this error yesterday, and I don't recall making any changes.  When I try the debugger, depending on the run, it varies which queries it takes me to, e.g. it originally landed on the first query, now it no longer lands on that one but on some later ones instead, so it seems arbitrary which queries it complains about.
All of the queries seem to run just fine when executed manually, outside of the window "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications", so no syntax issues.  Any ideas what went wrong?
I looked at Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 1. (Access 2007), and none of these issues seem to apply to my queries.screenshot.  Here's an example of one of the queries that originally seemed to trigger this error, but no longer does in spite of no changes, since it seems arbitrary where the debugger lands:
Query titled "nulling TB-r public fields":
UPDATE [current Regionals] 
SET [current Regionals].[TB-r_public] = Null, [current Regionals].[TB-r_s_public] = Null, 
    [current Regionals].[TB-r_com_public] = Null;

STATUS UPDATE:
I identified the problem! I renamed some of the fields used in the WHERE statements, and it is still looking for the old names, even though when I open up the SQL in Access it now displays the new names so you wouldn't think it's a problem.  And strangely, not all the queries that include the renamed fields throw this error, but most do. Is there a way to fix it other than reverting to the old field names (if that would even fix it?)?  It was confusing having them named _new when they are now obsolete values that I still need to calculate the new values from, that's why I renamed them.  Thanks for any suggestions!
NEW STATUS UPDATE:
I tried changing the field names back to their original names to avoid throwing this error that was a result of name changes, but the modules still throw the error.
SOLUTION:
I had to reopen every query involving the fields with name changes in design view, and resave them (no changes), and that solved the problem!

this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516396/error-3061-too-few-parameters-2-expected

There are naming rules that must be followed when a query is executed via code that are not an issue when running via the query builder.

Thanks, Bart.  I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516396/error-3061-too-few-parameters-2-expected as you suggested, and the most popular solution was to bracket the field names, which my SQL queries do, and to see what's going on in the immediate window.  I can't open the immediate window--it has a red exclamation mark on the view menu and nothing happens when I try to open...  What are the naming rules that I may be violating?  Thanks in advance for clarifying!

Run them one at a time via code to find the query(s) that are causing the issue

Since you used brackets, spaces and punctuation/special characters should not be issue but really should avoid those in naming convention. Could post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours for analysis.

Set a breakpoint and step through code. All queries are saved objects, not statements constructed in VBA? All these queries are UPDATE actions?

Thanks, June7. Yes, all are update actions saved as query objects
